# Wordpress child theme style.css not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a file structure in the same format as my parent theme. My parent theme is called Alpine and within Alpine there is a functions.php and style.css file. There do not appear to be any additional style.css files.

I have created a directory called Alpine-child and within that I have created a functions.php and style.css file.

I can't work out why any changes I make to the child style.css are not implemented but they are when I make the same changes in parent style.css

This is my child style.css:

```html
/*
 Theme Name:   Alpine Child
 Theme URI:    http://www.creative-ispiration.com/wp/alpine/
 Description:  My first child theme, based on Alpine
 Author:       MilkshakeThemes
 Author URI:   http://themeforest.net/user/milkshakethemes
 Template:     Alpine
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, post-formats, rtl$
 Text Domain: alpine-child
*/
```

This is my child functions.php file:

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your project?

Comment: I am currently hosting the website on an AWS EC2 Instance. I have been editing the website via SSH. This is the current developement address: http://ec2-52-211-25-124.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Take a look at your `<head>` tag. More importantly look at the order of your stylesheets.

The styles from your child theme are being added first and then all the styles from your parent theme. This will cause the styles from the parent theme to override your child theme styles.

You can change the priority of your `my_theme_enqueue_styles` function to run after the parent by using the third parameter of [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). This will enqueue your child theme styles last and allow the CSS to work as expected.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 11 );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
?>
```

Comment: Can I just copy the php above into my functions.php file to change the order?

Comment: @GavinReynoldson Yes. I have just copied your original code and added a priority to your `add_action` call. Notice the `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 11 );` now has a third parameter which is the priority. This has been set to 11 because 10 is the default priority.

Comment: I have added the above to functions.php and there is still no change. When I check `head` the last file to load is parent-style. I can't see alpine-child/style.css having loaded at all.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson My apologies. Your function is running but I had the wrong stylesheet in the code I posted. I've updated my answer to add your child stylesheet and not your parent stylesheet.

Comment: Great. Please mark this answer as correct so this question can help someone else.

Comment: @Jrod, Thanks! I have posted the below code. It works for custom CSS. What about JS and other settings that it might not be capturing?

Comment: this does not work for twentytwentytwo theme, I used another method by Craig, that worked fine.

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'twentyseventeen-style'; 
    $child_style = 'twentyseventeen-child-style';
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $child_style, get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
?>
```

and none of the other answers did.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me and helped me realized why nothing else also worked.

Comment: this works after adding `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );`
thanks Craig

Answer (score 2):

After updating from Divi 4.4.1 to Divi 4.10.8 the Child theme parent CSS was not working. I did some research om my website and realized that Divi style.css file was empty with only header info (after the update) and that the code needed to show the CSS was now in a different file (style-static.min.css) I changed the file name in my Child Theme functions.php file from style.css to style-static.min.css. This solved my problem and the CSS is working.

See underneath the code I used:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 11);
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-static.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enqueue the child theme `style.css` so your function should be:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. I have actualy tried many variations and also attempted to use @import. Nothing seems to work. I have messaged the theme developer for support. Thanks

Comment: I think # get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' # might be referring back to the parent directory when you want the child directory.

Comment: @CraigHicks, It refers to the active theme, which in this case is the child theme.

Comment: @CraigHicks, If you take a look at the `get_stylesheet_uri()`, it internally calls the function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, so they can't return information of different themes :)

Comment: @AvagSargsyan - Thanks for your comment.  I switched to a static blog system: "Hexo", which is simpler yet suitable for my needs.  I had wanted to dig deeper to find out why the [config above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417478/4376643) was working while yours didn't.  I take your word for it that `get_stylesheet_uri()` was not the reason, so there must be another reason.  But now Wordpress is far far away.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Craig Hick's answer worked for me and I also realize why my default code from the Wordpress documentation wasn't working.

```
  <?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ); 
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    ); }
```

In my case, the line **wp_get_theme()->get('Version')** returned **1.0.0** which was the same version number as the parent theme.
So I just changed the  child theme css version number to **1.0.1** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My child theme currently has the following code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

//load child theme custom CSS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 11 );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

?>
```

Previously, the code I used only had the first part before `//load child theme custom CSS` part, and it was unable to get the custom CSS. I have added the code @jrod suggested above and it worked. I need to confirm with you guys that my child theme code is complete, and I don't have to add anything else. I am not sure if this also fetches the custom JS files I have in the child theme JS files.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove version from comment in child them style.css it's working for me in wordpress 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I was using the same version 1.0.0 in both of parents and child theme, after i changed the version of child theme to 1.0.1 it worked for me